# Django CBV detailview get_context_data not passing id to the query

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique = True )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, default='')
    floors = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, default='')
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Flat(models.Model):
    FACING_CHOICES = [
        ('east', 'East'),
        ('west', 'West'),
        ('north', 'North'),
        ('south', 'South'),
    ]
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('sold', 'Sold'),
        ('available', 'Available'),
        ('mortgage', 'Mortgage'),
    ]
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flatno = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    flatarea = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    facing = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                            choices=FACING_CHOICES,
                            default='east')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                            default='available')
        
Views.py
        
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/project_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['totalavailable_flats'] = Flat.objects.filter (project_id = self.kwargs.get('id')) .count()
        return context

template
projects/project_detail.html 

{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<p>{{ project.finishdate }}</p>
<p>Available flats : {{ total_flats }}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

How to pass the Project_id to the query to get flat details
Query - Project id not passing to the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
FROM "projects_flat"
WHERE "projects_flat"."project_id" IS NULL
```

My view not passing project id to the query.

Comment: Which URL are you going to in your browser? Please show your URL patterns. Unless the ID is optional, it is better to use `self.kwargs['id']`. At the moment, `self.kwargs.get('id')` silently returns `None`, then you get the error in another place later.

Comment: As mentioned by user @Alasdair , it depends on your URL pattern.
In case you want to use the query string (`?id=..`), consider using `request.GET`.
Also, try to come up with a smaller (minimal) example: your view function could simply access or output your desired id parameter, nothing else. To the problem, the following use of the id in a query is irrelevant.